# How can I make sure a function is not executed before 2 or more Observable have returned Data?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a Angular Reactive form which uses some custom components. It has some basic Form Fields as well as a Froala editor. I customize the editor with custom drop downs which get the values from a back end via observable. Here is where my problems start.
I have a function called `transformArr()` which looks like this

```js
transformArr() {
  console.log('Transform Contact Options')
  this.contactFields$ = this.mailTemplateService
    .templateLookup(this.guids.MAIL_TEMPLATE_CONTACT_FIELDS);
  this.contactFields$.subscribe(res => {
    this.contactFieldsOption = new Object() as {
      [key: string]: string
    };

    for (const each of res) {
      this.contactFieldsOption[each.value.replace('""', '&#34&#34')] = each.name;
    }
  })

  console.log('Transform Personal Options')
  this.personalFields$ = this.mailTemplateService
    .templateLookup(this.guids.MAIL_TEMPLATE_CONTACT_FIELDS);
  this.personalFields$.subscribe(res => {
    this.personalFieldsOption = new Object() as {
      [key: string]: string
    };

    for (const each of res) {
      this.personalFieldsOption[each.value.replace('""', '&#34&#34')] = each.name;
    }
  })
}
```

Only when both are completed i want to run `this.initializeEditor();`

Comment: How does [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) sound?

Comment: Based on what i see that would mean rewrite all fictions as each of them right now has its observable and we subscribe to each to transform returned arrays. Maybe create another observable which watches some values and if they all a true then go and run the initiateEditor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this using [**`forkJoin`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

Here, give this a try:

```
transformArr() {

  console.log('Transform Contact Options');

  this.contactFieldsOption$ = this.mailTemplateService
    .templateLookup(this.guids.MAIL_TEMPLATE_CONTACT_FIELDS)
    .pipe(map(res => {
      this.contactFieldsOption = new Object() as {
        [key: string]: string
      };

      for (const each of res) {
        this.contactFieldsOption[each.value.replace('""', '&#34&#34')] = each.name;
      }
      return this.contactFieldsOption;
    }));

  console.log('Transform Personal Options');

  this.personalFieldsOption$ = this.mailTemplateService
    .templateLookup(this.guids.MAIL_TEMPLATE_CONTACT_FIELDS)
    .pipe(map(res => {
      this.personalFieldsOption = new Object() as {
        [key: string]: string
      };

      for (const each of res) {
        this.personalFieldsOption[each.value.replace('""', '&#34&#34')] = each.name;
      }
      return this.personalFieldsOption;
    }));

  return forkJoin(this.contactFieldsOption$, this.personalFieldsOption$);
}
```

And then somewhere down the line:

```
this.transformArr().subscribe(
  ([contactFieldsOption, personalFieldsOption]) => this.initializeEditor()
)
```

I haven't tested this out. But don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.

Let me know if this doesn't.

Hope it helps :)